# How do I upgrade Bash in Mac OSX Mountain Lion and set it the correct path?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

since Mountain Lion still uses the old bash 3.x, I was wondering if there is a good tutorial (or if somebody could post one here) on how to upgrade bash to the latest version. Also, it would be helpful to know how to set the path so that it can be used in terminal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for http://apple.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24632/is-it-safe-to-upgrade-bash-via-homebrew

Comment: This question has suddenly become [extremely relevant, see Shellshock](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=au&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q=shellshock&oq=shellshock)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

- Update brew: `brew update`
- Install bash with `brew install bash`
- Add `/usr/local/bin/bash` to `/etc/shells`
- Change the default shell with `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash`

You don't normally have to change any settings in Terminal or iTerm 2. Both of them default to opening new shells with the default login shell.

Comment: would you recommend upgrading bash. I read in your linked article that there is a chance that you can lock yourself out.

Comment: @Tom I edited the answer, but if you get locked out, you can change the default shell from System Preferences or just change the login command in Terminal or iTerm.

Comment: @kristi I renamed /usr/local/bin/bash as /usr/local/bin/bash4 because I want to keep bash 3.2 as my default for the moment. Rationale: as a sys engineer, I need some kind of reminder that some things that are easily and routinely done in bash4 need a workaround in bash 3. Grrr!!!

Comment: @kristi - in other words, I executed step 1 of your instruction set and stayed away from steps 2 and 3 of your instruction set.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!