# Bash 'read' command does not accept -i parameter on Mac. Any alternatives?

Tags: macos, bash

I have a bash script that works fine on my work Ubuntu machine, but sadly breaks when I try and run it on my Mac OSX <strike>Lion</strike> Mountain Lion laptop. The line that kills it is this:

```
while [[ -z "$SSHFS_PATH" ]] ; do
  read -e -p "Please enter the path on which to mount your file system: `echo -e $'\n > '`" -i "~/aws-dev" SSHFS_PATH;
done
```

It throws out this error:

```
-bash: read: -i: invalid option
read: usage: read [-ers] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-p prompt] [-a array] [-n nchars] [-d delim] [name ...]
```

So it seems the OSX version of the read command doesn't accept `-i`, which is used to suggest default values. Why? And what can be done to fix this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mac OS X 10.7 Lion (and to this date all more recent versions as well, thanks @kojiro) ships with `bash 3.2` whereas `read -i` was introduced with `bash 4.0-alpha` (see the [ChangeLog](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES)).

You can either install a more recent version of `bash` using [`homebrew`](http://brew.sh/) or provide a non-readline default value yourself, e.g.

```
read -p "Path? (default: /bar): " var
[ -z "${var}" ] && var='/bar'
```

Comment: [Here's evidence](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/os-x-109/) that OS 10.9 still ships with bash 3.

Comment: Thanks- this did work for me, but doesn't have the exact same behaviour, as one can actually modify the pre-populated version in the `read -i` version. I think I'll just put a `if [[ ${BASH_VERSION:0:1} < 4 ]] ; then ...` message in that explains to upgrade Bash with Homebrew or the like!

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with "non-readline". With stock options you cannot portably emulate this behaviour, unfortunately.

Comment: (FWIW, I'd use `${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}` directly instead of parsing `$BASH_VERSION`. Seems a bit more elegant and robust.)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip. It's a real bugger that Mac doesn't ship with the latest Bash. And that doing anything with Mac package managers is always a ballache. I wish they could have something as good and solid as `apt-get` or `yum`. Oh well!

Comment: I agree, but I guess that's the gap that `homebrew` is trying to fill. Then there's also [Gentoo Prefix](https://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/) which brings `portage` to your Mac, but these days it's probably easier to just use `homebrew`.

Answer (score 2):

One could write a wrapper function that detects whether `-i` is supported and use the appropriate syntax:

```
function readinput() {
  local CLEAN_ARGS=""
  while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    local i="$1"
    case "$i" in
      "-i")
        if read -i "default" 2>/dev/null <<< "test"; then 
          CLEAN_ARGS="$CLEAN_ARGS -i \"$2\""
        fi
        shift
        shift
        ;;
      "-p")
        CLEAN_ARGS="$CLEAN_ARGS -p \"$2\""
        shift
        shift
        ;;
      *)
        CLEAN_ARGS="$CLEAN_ARGS $1"
        shift
        ;;
    esac
  done
  eval read $CLEAN_ARGS
}
```

and then

```
readinput -e -p "This is a test of... " -i "default value" variable
variable=${variable:-default value}
```

**Note**: if you call this function `read`, it will then replace the not-so-functional builtin.

Answer (score 1):

OSX bash is version 3. Linux users enjoy the additional features of bash version 4.

Using parameter substitution `${VAR:-def-value}` if $VAR is unset then def-value is returned.

```
DEFPATH="~/aws-dev"
while [[ -z "$SHFS_PATH" ]] ; do
    echo "Please enter the path on which to mount your file system"
    read -p "default is $DEFPATH " SHFS_PATH
    SHFS_PATH=${SHFS_PATH:-~/aws-dev}
    echo $SHFS_PATH
done
```

Comment: I'm going to do the same now - why suffer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, suspectus, but it didn't actually work for me. Whatever I put in, `$SHFS_PATH` (sic) has the `DEFPATH` value.

Comment: duh! I left $SHFS_PATH - should be SHFS_PATH (without the `$`)

Comment: Ah, makes sense :) PS, I'm trying to upgrade with Homebrew but it seems to be trying to do a Curl fetch to a Gist file that doesn't exist...

Comment: It says: Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/curl -f#LA Homebrew\ 0.9.3\ (Ruby\ 1.8.7-358;\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 10.8.4) https://raw.github.com/gist/4008180/443bc2c712ca9151a9e34e13be1b3a00e9a190d0/bash-4.2-001-039.patch -o 000-homebrew.diff

Comment: This post has useful info on installing bash4 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416195/how-do-i-upgrade-bash-in-mac-osx-mountain-lion-and-set-it-the-correct-path

Comment: It's cowardly refusing- also, I can't imagine that sudo would stop a certain patch file hitting a 404. I've messaged the maintainer about it anyway, but it's unrelated to this question, really! :)