# How do I read user input into a variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, input

How do I read user input into a variable in Bash?

```bash
fullname=""
# Now, read user input into the variable `fullname`.
```

Comment: see also [Read a variable in bash with a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642585/read-a-variable-in-bash-with-a-default-value) - tldr: `read -e -p "some prompt: " -i "default value" some_var; echo "$some_var"`

Answer (score 399, accepted):

Use [`read -p`](https://ss64.com/bash/read.html):

```
# fullname="USER INPUT"
read -p "Enter fullname: " fullname
# user="USER INPUT"
read -p "Enter user: " user
```

If you like to get the user's confirmation:

```
read -p "Continue? (Y/N): " confirm && [[ $confirm == [yY] || $confirm == [yY][eE][sS] ]] || exit 1
```

You should also quote your variables to prevent pathname expansion and word splitting with spaces:

```
# passwd "$user"
# mkdir "$home"
# chown "$user:$group" "$home"
```

Comment: You can use ``${confirm^^} == 'YES'`` .

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko That's a usual method other people use but it's only compatible with 4.0+.

Answer (score 23):

Yep, you'll want to do something like this:

```
echo -n "Enter Fullname: " 
read fullname
```

Another option would be to have them supply this information on the command line.  Getopts is your best bet there.

[Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options)

Answer (score 19):

Try this

```
#/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a word: " word
echo "You entered $word"
```

Answer (score 11):

##### Maximally portable (bash, zsh, ...):

```bash
printf "%s" "Enter fullname: "
read fullname
```

This is the most portable way to read with prompt. Methods such as `read -p` and `echo -n` are more likely to fail depending on the shell.

Answer (score 5):

Also you can try [zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/) !

```
user=$(zenity --entry --text 'Please enter the username:') || exit 1
```

Answer (score 4):

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html

> One line is read from the standard input, or from the file descriptor
> fd supplied as an argument to the -u option, split into words as
> described above in Word Splitting, and the first word is assigned to
> the first name, the second word to the second name, and so on. If
> there are more words than names, the remaining words and their
> intervening delimiters are assigned to the last name.

```
echo "bash is awesome." | (read var1 var2; echo -e "Var1: $var1 \nVar2: $var2")
```

`bash` will be var1
`is awesome` will be var2
`echo -e`     enable interpretation of backslash escapes from [ubuntu](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/echo.1.html) manual.

---

so the full code can be:

```
echo -n "Enter Fullname: "
read fullname
echo "your full name is $fullname."
echo -n "test type more than 2 word: "
read var1 var2; echo -e
read var1 var2; echo -e "Var1: $var1 \nVar2: $var2")
```