# Passing user input value from batch file to shell script

Tags: linux, windows, shell, batch-file, scripting

I have a task where I have to write a batch script in which I take input from user and call a shell script from there passing the user input value. Any idea how I can achieve this.

Below is the bat file where I take input from user and finally call the shell script named test(test.sh) which contains curl command

```
@echo off
set /p technology="Enter technology: "
set /p job_name="Enter job name : "
set /p url="Enter url : "
test.sh
```

Comment: Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31414/how-can-i-pass-a-command-line-argument-into-a-shell-script

Comment: Why do you not directly take input in that shell script? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544359/how-to-read-user-input-into-a-variable-in-bash/18546416

Answer (score 1):

Since according to your tags, the shell script is a POSIX shell, and the Batch script is Windows batch, you can take the advantage that Windows puts the variables it sets by default into the environment. Hence the variables should be parameter-expandable inside your shell script as `$technology` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response.
The answer I was looking for is

in batch script

```
@echo off
set /p technology="Enter technology: "
set /p job_name="Enter job name : "
set /p url="Enter url : "
test.sh %technology% %job_name% %url%
```

While in the shell script

```
echo "technology = $1"
echo "job name = $2"
echo "url = $3"
```

The reason for passing value this way is, I wanted to pass value received from user.
Here $1, $2, $3 refers to the values passed according to their passed parameters.

While in the shell script with curl command

```
"url" : "'$3'"
```