# What is the purpose of `-i` in `read` in bash? How do you use it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I thought this:

```bash
read -p "Make this rsync backup session a dry run [Y/n]? " -i '--dry-run' dry_run
echo "$dry_run"
```

...would output `--dry-run` as its "default value" if I just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to reply to the prompt. But, it doesn't. It outputs a newline.

What is the purpose of `-i` and how does it work?

From `help read`:

```
-i text   use TEXT as the initial text for Readline
```

For anyone who wants to see where I learned how to make a bash prompt to the user: [How do I read user input into a variable in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18546416/4561887)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-i` option only works together with the `-e` option to enable using Readline, and it prefills its contents on the prompt:

```bash
read -ep "Make this rsync backup session a dry run [Y/n]? " -i '--dry-run'
```

prints this prompt:

```bash
Make this rsync backup session a dry run [Y/n]? --dry-run
```

where the `--dry-run` part is editable.

Comment: No longer works in `5.2.26(1)-release`. The `--dry-run` doesn't appear in the editing buffer.

Comment: @whatthe It does work for me in Bash 5.2

Comment: Though that's 5.2.15, and I see at least [two patches that touched readline](https://github.com/bminor/bash/compare/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814...f3b6bd19457e260b65d11f2712ec3da56cef463f) since then.