# Bash script with conditions (if, case) works incorrect

Tags: linux, bash, conditional-operator

I tried to create bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Where are you now?"
read $city

if [[ $city == "Kyiv" ]] && [[ $city == "Berlin" ]] && [[$city == "California"]];
then
        case $city in
        Kyiv)
        echo "Ukraine";;
        Berlin)
        echo "Germany";;
        California)
        echo "USA"
  esac

else
        echo  "$city Its not the city"
fi
```

And always output:

`It’s not the city`

I check a lot of documentation but can't find problem.

Also,

Tried to use conditional without 'case':

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Where are you now?"
read $city
if [[ $city == "Kyiv" ]]
then
        echo "Ukraine"
elif [[ $city == "Berlin" ]]
then
        echo "Germany"
elif [[ $city == "California" ]]
then
        echo "USA"
else
        echo " $city Its not the city"
fi
```

but same output:

`It’s not the city`

Comment: You probably wanted logical OR operator `||` instead of AND `&&`.

Comment: `read city` not `read $city`

Comment: California is a state (not a city).

Comment: there a few syntax issues with the code; cut-n-paste your code (with shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the recommended changes

Comment: you are expecting the variable `city` to be all of the cities at the **same** time. Since we don't do quantum computing, this is fairly impossible. You should use the _or_ operator (`||`) instead of the _and_ operator (`&&`).

Comment: To expand on KamilCuk's comment, your `read $city` statement is incorrect (in this context, at least).  The correct syntax is `read VARNAME`, with `VARNAME` being a valid variable identifier.  If you type `read $VARNAME` (and VARNAME has never been initialised before), Bash will first _expand_ the variable (to the null string), and then perform `read`, which will store the input into the `REPLY` default variable. More info [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html).

Comment: You can also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544359/how-do-i-read-user-input-into-a-variable-in-bash)

Comment: @kvantour, Schrödinger's city?

Comment: @glennjackman yes, when you know it's name, you can't locate the city, but when the city is located, you don't know which one it is.

Comment: Why do you have the `case` guarded by the `if` at all?  The general form for this should not include the `if` but should just look like `case $city in a) ...;; b) ...;; *) echo "Unknown city" >&2;; esac` where the default case `*` is executed when the city does not match any of the other cases.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Where are you now?"

read -r city

 if [[ $city == "Kyiv" ]]  || [[ $city == "Berlin" ]] || [[ $city == "California" ]];

 then

 case $city in

 Kyiv)
 echo "Ukraine";;

 esac

 case $city in

 Berlin)

 echo "Germany";;

 esac

 case $city in
 California) 
 echo "USA";;
 *)
 esac
 else
 echo " $city It's not the city "

fi
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).