# bash let variable default to user input

Tags: bash, shell, variable-expansion

I want to write a script for both interactive and batch use. If arguments are not provided the script will ask for the users input.

Unlike [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642585/read-a-variable-in-bash-with-a-default-value) the user shouldn't be bothered if the variable is already defined by arguments.

Using parameter expansion I tried this:

```
${FILE="$( echo "Please provide the file:" >&2 ; read a; echo $a )"}
```

... but I always get a `command not found` error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try the following script.    echo "Enter your name" ; 
read name;  
if [ ${#name} -eq 0 ]  
then  
        echo -e "\nName: Horst"  
else  
        echo -e "\nName: $name"  
fi

Comment: Just answered it on my own: `FILE=${FILE="$( echo "Please provide the file:" >&2 ; read a; echo $a )"}`
It's some sort of double assingment, but it works!

Comment: Try This:  echo ${FILE="$( echo "Please provide the file:" >&2 ; read a; echo $a )"}

Comment: Stop answering questions in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write

```
# earlier in program, $FILE may or may not be defined

if [[ -z $FILE ]]; then
    read -p "Please provide the file: " FILE
fi
```

If you really want to cram it into one line, use the `:` command and the assignment expansion syntax

```
: ${FILE:=$(read -p "file?"; echo "$REPLY")}
```

Note, don't use ALL_CAPS_VARS: [someday you'll use `PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310594/ls-not-found-after-running-read-path) and wonder why your script is broken.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! I check half a dozen variables this way, so a one-liner is the only solution to keep the code concise

Comment: I'd recommend something in between: `[[ -z $FILE ]] && read -p "..." FILE`

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
FILE="$( echo "Please provide the file:" >&2 ; read a; echo $a )"
```

You are trying to execute the command instead of initialization

```
${FILE="$( echo "Please provide the file:" >&2 ; read a; echo $a )"}
Please provide the file:
Mahesh
-bash: Mahesh: command not found
$ FILE="$( echo "Please provide the file:" >&2 ; read a; echo $a )"
Please provide the file:
mahesh
$ echo $FILE
mahesh
```