# What is meant by :- this symbol in unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

Can anyone please tell me what is mean by `:-` this symbol in Unix shell scripting

`while [ ${runq:-$SLOTS} -ge $SLOTS ]` in the given example

Comment: It's a bash thing - for providing default values - see e.g. http://jaduks.livejournal.com/7934.html

Comment: @Paul It's not a bash thing, [it should work in any POSIX-compliant shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02).

Comment: @TomFenech: thanks for the clarification and the useful link - I'm not too familiar with shells other than bash.

Comment: Removing the down vote. This is a valid question for new shell script users.

Comment: @PinakiMukherjee, ...however, downvotes are valid when a question "doesn't show research effort"; failing to search for duplicates before asking a new question qualifies. We already have one instance (actually, several) in the knowledgebase; adding more of them creates no value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple way to provide a default value using an expansion. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value for more information.

There are also answers to similar questions on stackoverflow like [Read a variable in bash with a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642585/read-a-variable-in-bash-with-a-default-value)