# Bash Read Input - Tab the Prompt

Tags: bash

I've got a script that I'm reading the input from users. Here's my code:

```
if [ -z $volreadexists ]; then
        echo -e "\tThis will overwrite the entire volume (/dev/vg01/$myhost)...are you sure?"
        read REPLY
        echo
        if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
            echo -e "\t\tContinuing"
            syncvolume
        else
            echo "Fine...skipping"
        fi
    fi
```

I'm having to use `read REPLY` because `read` by itself doesn't insert tabs. What I'm looking for is something similar to:

```
read -p "\tDoes this look OK? (n for No)" -n 1 -r
```

Where `\t` would tab over the read prompt.

How can I add tabs to a read prompt?

UPDATE: Thanks for the great answer from @gniourf!:

```
read -p $'\tDoes this look OK? (n for No)' -n 1 -r
```

However, I found an issue. When I attempt to use a variable there it doesn't translate it:

```
read -p $'\tThis will overwrite the entire volume (/dev/vg01/$myhost)...are you sure? ' -n 1 -r
```

becomes

```
        This will overwrite the entire volume (/dev/vg01/$myhost)...are you sure?
```

where I want:

```
        This will overwrite the entire volume (/dev/vg01/server1)...are you sure?
```

Using doublequotes doesn't work either :(

Any ideas?

Comment: Just use [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting): `read -p $'\tDoes this look OK? (n for No)' -n 1 -r`

Comment: Looks good!! Sweet, thx!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You should really add that as an answer so that it can be upvoted and (more importantly) accepted.

Comment: Yes, add an answer - get karma :)

Comment: That's because `$"..."` does something else entirely. But you aren't restricted to a single set of quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

```
read -p $'\tDoes this look OK? (n for No)' -n 1 -r
```

---

Now, if you want to use variable expansions too, you can mix different quotes like so:

```
read -p $'\t'"This will overwrite the entire volume (/dev/vg01/$myhost)...are you sure? " -n 1 -r
```

Here I only used ANSI-C quoting for the tab character. Make sure you don't leave any spaces between `$'\t'` and `"This will...."`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up referencing this answer:

[Read a variable in bash with a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642585/read-a-variable-in-bash-with-a-default-value)

and created a workaround. It's not perfect, but it works:

```
myhost="server1"
if [ -z $volreadexists ]; then
    read -e -i "$myhost" -p $'\tJust checking if it\'s OK to overwrite volume at /dev/vg01/'
    echo
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^$myhost[Yy]$ ]]; then
        echo -e "\t\tContinuing"
    else
        echo "Fine...skipping"
    fi
fi
```