# Bash: how can I read user input while supplying some default answer?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, user-input

Currently I am using `printf` and `read` or `read -p` to prompt the user and gather his input.

However, for some of my scripts it would be *very* useful to supply editable default answers, like:

```
Please specify the correct path to your file:
/some/long/ugly/default/path/to/user.file       # <-- this line should be
                                                #     editable and read
                                                #     back in after the
                                                #     user hits [ENTER]
```

At the moment my script prints `/some/long/...` and asks if this is already correct by prompting `correct? [y/n]`.

If the user hits `n` the user gets prompted for a custom path. However, in this scenario the user has to enter the full path by hand. Since mostly only the last directory or file changes, I would like to supply a "default answer" that is editable by the user. Thus, the user just has to change the filename, for example, and hit [ENTER].

Reading `man read` looks like `read` can not do this?

Is this task rather complicated? Or are there tools available similar to `read` that allow such behavior?

Comment: this answer seems to meet all your requirements: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6703730/4082052

Comment: Oh my god...I think I was blind :/ Thank you very much!

Comment: Started flagging this post as a duplicate...